# Type casting for printf but not otherwise

Tags: c, casting, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to convert from bytes to float in JNI. If I type cast it when calling the GetByteArrayElements method, it does not work. Printing out the float variable prints out a pointer instead. I know it is a pointer because usually it is something like "123451234993305848212225.000000" However, if I type cast it as float in the printf statement, it displays the correct value. Why does this happen? I have the two sets of code fragments below -

```
jbyte *testTensor_data = (env)->GetByteArrayElements(NV21FrameData,0);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Torchandroid", "C test print: %f",(float) (testTensor_data[0]));
```

This works. The print statement displays the correct number.

```
jfloat *testTensor_data = (float*) (env)->GetByteArrayElements(NV21FrameData,0);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Torchandroid", "C test print: %f",(testTensor_data[0]));
```

This second method does not work. Problem is, simply printing out a float is not useful to me. I need to use it as a float and manipulate it as a float which is the second method and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples are not equal. `testTensor_data[0]` is a `jbyte` (`sizeof(jbyte)==1`) in the first case, and a `float` (`sizeof(jfloat)==4`) in the second case. It's not a pointer it is printing, but about 4 bytes that are casted into a single float.

In order to handle 12bit data with some convinience, you can do something like:

```
struct 3pix {
    int a:12;
    int b:12;
};
```

in the hope that it will not be padded, and then accessing `((struct 3pix*)test_Tensor_data)->a` or something like that. I think it won't be easy. Another solution - more natural - is to use bitwise operations, but you'll have to get the calculations right.

Comment: I get these as Camera images from the Android camera in the NV21 format. Those are 12 bits per pixel. How can they fit into a jbytearray then?

Also, 4 bytes is 32 bits so the most that printf statement can show me is 2^32. It shows me a number a lot larger than that. Like several orders of magnitude larger.

Comment: no, no, the maximum value for float is much more than 2^32. Something like 3.4 x 10^38. The maximum value for a 32bit pointer is indeed 2^32-1

Comment: @maverick1989 manipulating 12 bit is a bit complicated. you'll have to extract it using bitwise operations, manipulate normal `int`, and squeeze it back.

Comment: So what you are saying is that since float can store 4 bytes, multiple (4 to be precise) numbers (or bytes) from GetByteArrayElements is pushed into the first array location? So testTensor_data[0] actually carries the first four bytes returned by GetByteArrayElements?

Comment: That is very unfortunate. This is an image processing application so doing all those computations simply to first convert it to a float is going to take up a LOT of time. Thanks for your help anyways.